# Send a huge content range using streams

Tags: node.js, pipe, partial, httpserver

How to send a part of file using read stream in response on HTTP request?

I want to send an arbitrary `Content-Range` of a huge file.

I can't use events when I do `fs.createReadStream('hugeFile.bin').pipe(response)` to filter out a part of readable stream. I can create a fake writable stream, which omits (like `> /dev/null`) a part of data, but `chunk` size may be not a multiple of a first part to send.

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options.

In particular, the `start` and `end` options - these let you set the byte offsets in the file to start and stop reading from.

So basically you'd do:

```
fs.createReadStream('hugeFile.bin', { start: firstByte, end: lastByte }).pipe(response)
```

or the moral equivalent and it'd do what you want.

Comment: If I do `response.statusCode = 216;` then `response.setHeader('Content-Range', 'bytes ' + start + '-' + (end - 1) + '/' + stat.size);`, then what should I do to send the file contents via stream? Should I call `response.end();` after the code line you wrote?

Comment: Or instead should I do `response.end();` in on `'end'` event handler of `fs.createReadStream('hugeFile.bin', { start: firstByte, end: lastByte })` object?

Comment: response.end will be called automatically when the source stream ends. It should just work.

Comment: So if I want to send a plenty of files parts, it is not possible if I need streams to meet a memory issues?